# Moving XUL window

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm working on an app, which is based on Firefox and what I need to build is an in-app password manager.  I'm planning to populate it once and hide it from view outside of the window frame, bringing it in-frame when it is needed.  Now, I have read about the rules applied to moveTo, namely

"You can't move a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.

You can't move a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab."

I was wondering if there are any exceptions to that rule?  I have full access to chrome, so I was wondering if there's some more low-level way to achieve the moveTo form there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you moving a XUL window? If so, what does "hide it from view outside of the window frame" mean? Do you mean moving the XUL window off-screen?

Comment: Yes.  One of the requirements is to have it appear in an animated fashion, plus I don't want to recreate it every time it needs to be envoked, so I was thinking of stashing it off-screen.

Comment: Even if Gecko allowed to move windows off-screen, you would still have a problem with task manager showing your window.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not worried about that.  The app is heavily modified, so no task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restrictions of `window.moveTo()` don't apply to code running with system privileges. I just tried typing `top.moveTo(-1000, 0)` into the Error Console - it moved the window off-screen, something that unprivileged code isn't allowed to do. Still, opening the window off-screen is not possible as far as I know (you can however move it in a `load` event handler, when the window is still invisible). Also, the task manager still shows that window - it is possible to Alt-Tab to it, then press Alt-Space and choose "Move" from that system menu (that's on Windows).

Comment: I am able to use moveTo from the console.  However, when I try to do it form a .jsm file, nothing happens.  Do you know how to make my code run with system privileges?

Comment: @Lukich: JavaScript modules always run with system privileges. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I see.  Thanks fot that bit of info, I'll investigate further.

Comment: You were right.  I had centerscreen set on window.open.  Removing it did the trick.  Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.